# How to edit a PayPal API field name?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

My boss wants to change the description field name in the [PayPal API](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr).

I'm not the one who implemented the API in the website. Do I need the account from the developer who implemented the PayPal API in the website to login to PayPal in order to edit the field name?

The website is made in **Wordpress**.

Please see [the site here](http://petlet.net.au/how-to-pay-for-bookings/). Try to book, and after that you will see this:

[image]

I want to change the 'Descriptions' field name.

Comment: This is a bit unclear, if you mean the label for the field on your website, then you probably don't need any account access - you can just edit what's on your site. But your question is very vague, you probably need to show how it is integrated on your site.

Comment: I updated my post please check to be more clear @TimMalone